# Docker failed to install cURL (version 7.10.5 or later is required)

Tags: php, docker, curl, docker-compose, dockerfile

I'm having an error when I'm trying to install **Stripe** using `docker` and `composer.json`.

Here is my `composer.json`:

```
{
"require": {
    "smarty/smarty": "^3.1",
    "stripe/stripe-php": "^6.13"
    }
}
```

my `Dockerfile`

```
FROM php:7.2.6-apache
RUN docker-php-ext-install mysqli curl
```

and the log of the error when I `docker-compose up`

```
Build complete.
Don't forget to run 'make test'.

Installing shared extensions:     /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20170718/
Installing header files:          /usr/local/include/php/
find . -name \*.gcno -o -name \*.gcda | xargs rm -f
find . -name \*.lo -o -name \*.o | xargs rm -f
find . -name \*.la -o -name \*.a | xargs rm -f
find . -name \*.so | xargs rm -f
find . -name .libs -a -type d|xargs rm -rf
rm -f libphp.la       modules/* libs/*
Configuring for:
PHP Api Version:         20170718
Zend Module Api No:      20170718
Zend Extension Api No:   320170718
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /bin/grep
checking for egrep... /bin/grep -E
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /bin/sed
checking for cc... cc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether cc accepts -g... yes
checking for cc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking how to run the C preprocessor... cc -E
checking for icc... no
checking for suncc... no
checking whether cc understands -c and -o together... yes
checking for system library directory... lib
checking if compiler supports -R... no
checking if compiler supports -Wl,-rpath,... yes
checking build system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
checking host system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
checking target system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
checking for PHP prefix... /usr/local
checking for PHP includes... -I/usr/local/include/php -I/usr/local/include/php/main -I/usr/local/include/php/TSRM -I/usr/local/include/php/Zend -I/usr/local/include/php/ext -I/usr/local/include/php/ext/date/lib
checking for PHP extension directory... /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20170718
checking for PHP installed headers prefix... /usr/local/include/php
checking if debug is enabled... no
checking if zts is enabled... no
checking for re2c... re2c
checking for re2c version... 0.16 (ok)
checking for gawk... no
checking for nawk... nawk
checking if nawk is broken... no
checking for cURL support... yes, shared
checking for pkg-config... /usr/bin/pkg-config
checking for libcurl.pc... using default path
checking for cURL 7.10.5 or greater... configure: error: cURL version 7.10.5 or later is required to compile php with cURL support
ERROR: Service 'www' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c docker-php-ext-install mysqli curl' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

I can't find any fix, or what I'm doing wrong. Thanks for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution given by a friend of mine. cURL was already inside the php package, no need to install it. But it was more complicated. My `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM composer AS vendor

COPY composer.json .
COPY composer.lock .
RUN composer install

FROM php:7.3-apache

COPY --from=vendor /app/vendor/ vendor/
COPY www ./

RUN mkdir templates_c
RUN mkdir cache
RUN chown www-data:www-data templates_c cache

VOLUME /var/www/html/templates_c/
VOLUME /var/www/html/cache/

RUN docker-php-ext-install mysqli
```

My `docker-compose.yml`

```
version: "2"
services:
    www:
        build: .
        ports: 
            - "80:80"
        volumes:
            - ./www/lib:/var/www/html/lib
            - ./www/modules:/var/www/html/modules
            - ./www/theme:/var/www/html/theme
            - ./www/index.php:/var/www/html/index.php
            - ./www/notes.php:/var/www/html/notes.php
            - ./www/tuto_array.php:/var/www/html/tuto_array.php
        links:
            - db
        networks:
            - default
```

Comment: You should also copy `composer.lock` into the first build stage, otherwise install will always download the latest package versions.

Answer (score 1):

The "docker-php-ext-install" helper script is aimed at installing PHP extensions, not system packages. In your Dockerfile you will need something like the following:

```sh
FROM php:7.2.6-apache
RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get install -y curl && apt-get clean -y
RUN docker-php-ext-install mysqli
```

The `mysqli` is a PHP extension so it should be ok. (I would suggest using PDO but that is a different conversation.)

Comment: Hi david, error when `docker-compose up` :  `Lock file, outdated dependencies`. So I update it: `composer update --lock`. Here is the error: `Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - stripe/stripe-php v6.34.5 requires ext-curl * -> the requested PHP extension curl is missing from your system.`. I suppose I have to activate them in php.ini, where how to find this file?

Comment: Ah, ok. You need to the PHP exertion for curl. That is much clearer now.  Checkout this GitHub issue wherein they had a similar issue that looks to have been resolved: https://github.com/docker-library/php/issues/323 Looks like both apt-get needs to install the system dep. cURL AND docker-php-ext-install is needed to install ext-curl.

Comment: Added it in my Dockerfile: `FROM php:7.2.6-apache
RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get install -y curl libcurl3-dev && apt-get clean -y
RUN docker-php-ext-install mysqli` Same error: composer update --lock
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'curl' (tried: /usr/lib/php/20170718/curl (/usr/lib/php/20170718/curl: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /usr/lib/php/20170718/curl.so (/usr/lib/php/20170718/curl.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0

Comment: The error message indicated that the `apt-get install -y curl` did not install the system package cURL. I would check to see what the system package is named for Debian distros.